# SharedPreference with EditText String

Tags: java, android

It gives me an error when I execute the code, What I try to do is try to somehow take the value (String) that was inserted by the user in the alertDialog.
Error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

this is my .java

```
public void verificar(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    EditText b = findViewById(R.id.userName);
    String nombre = b.getText().toString(); //Obtengo el nombre que se inserto en el cuadro
    editor.putInt("lastScore",cont);
    editor.putString("lastNombre",nombre);
    editor.commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ranking.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

this is my XML, with an EditText

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Usted esta en el top10!. Desea figurar?"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    />
```

This is the method that has "verificar"

```
 public void deseaFigurar(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null))

            .setPositiveButton("Figurar" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        verificar();
                        finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No figurar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ranking.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    builder.show();


}
```

Comment: Is the `verifiar()` function called from within your Component class? If not, where are you calling it from?

Comment: Janzek, can you please post the start of the class and other classes or methods as required? As @Omari mentioned, we just want to know where you are calling the verifiar() function from?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: sorry for taking a long time to answer, I will post the method that calls "verifcar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `findViewById(R.id.userName)` with a view in dialog, you need to pass dialog to find it, I don't know when and how you init dialog but should use it like this: `dialog.findViewById(R.id.userName)`. You can quickly fix it by the change to your function parameter like below code, and pass your dialog to function arguments when called.

```
public void verificar(View dialogView){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    EditText b = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    String nombre = b.getText().toString(); //Obtengo el nombre que se inserto en el cuadro
    editor.putInt("lastScore",cont);
    editor.putString("lastNombre",nombre);
    editor.commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ranking.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Change your deseaFigurar function like below. Because when you call `findViewById(R.id.userName)`. It is a method belong to Activity to find a view in Activity layout so it will cause null exception because there is no EditText with userName id. You need to find it in your dialog view which was inflated.

```
public void deseaFigurar(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView)

            .setPositiveButton("Figurar" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        verificar(dialogView);
                        finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No figurar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ranking.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    builder.show();


}
```

Comment: I just edit my post, I posted the methos that has the method "verificar", can you check it?. Thank you for the answer sonhvp

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dialogView` instead of main view if you want to instantiate your `EditText` , because your widget belong the the view inflated in `dialog` . try to instantiate your `EditText` within  the dialog , and don't forget to make `EditText b` a global variable

use

```
  b = dialog.findViewById(R.id.userName);//in the dialog
```

instead of this :

```
 EditText b = findViewById(R.id.userName);//in verifiar()
```